# Yum updates broke PHP on AWS Linux. Curl unable to load

Tags: php, curl, amazon-ec2

I ran all the suggested updates via YUM (haven't done so in about 2 months)

Now, PHP isn't working. It shows:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/5.6/modules/curl.so' - /usr/local/firefox/libnss3.so: version `NSS_3.34' not found (required by /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4) in Unknown on line 0
```

This happens even with a simple PHP command such as `php -ver`

It seems YUM is also broken:"

```
$ sudo yum update
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   /usr/local/firefox/libnss3.so: version `NSS_3.34' not found (required by /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4)

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7.15 (default, Nov 28 2018, 22:38:08)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

How to fix?

Comment: Tried updating your php version?

Comment: No updates seem to work. YUM is broken: sudo yum update
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   /usr/local/firefox/libnss3.so: version `NSS_3.34' not found (required by /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4)

Comment: @Isaac the problem here isn't the PHP version, the problem is that his libcurl is compiled with a different-and-incompatible version of NSS than the version of libnns he has on his local system. anyway, this isn't a suitable question for stackoverflow - it's a question for https://superuser.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com (i'm not sure which fits better, tbh)